# mysql procedure: how can i use table name variables

Tags: mysql, variables, store

I have built a MySQL procedure.
i have to define v_table variable within procedure

Who can help me ?
Thanks
Paolo

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cur1;
     igmLoop: loop
        fetch cur1 into v_column,v_table;
         IF done THEN
          LEAVE igmLoop;
        END IF;
    update v_table set v_column=replace(v_column,'Ã ','a`');
     end loop igmLoop;
    close cur1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither table names, nor column names can be dynamic within a stored procedure. You need to assemble the sql statement as a string and execute it using [PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLICATE PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) statements. So, basically, you will create a prepared statement out of your query and execute it.

The linked documentation contains examples as well.

Comment: Yes, you can. However, if you plan to execute an update per iteration, then make sure that you call all 3 command, including the deallocate prepare in the iteration, otherwise mysql may hit the configurable prepared statement limit.

Comment: declare cur1 cursor for SELECT  concat(' update ', table_name, ' set ',column_name,'=replace(',column_name,','''','''')') as sq  FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'splotdb' AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char','nchar','ntext','nvarchar','text','varchar') ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;set sq='';    open cur1;
     igmLoop: loop
        fetch cur1 into sq;
         IF done THEN
          LEAVE igmLoop;
        END IF;
      PREPARE stmt FROM sq;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
       end loop igmLoop;
    close cur1;
END

Comment: 1. This is unreadable, edit your question and place the formatted code there. 2. Pls provide the exact error message.